# Will I run into international issues if I put smaller luggage inside bigger luggage?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, international-travel

I'm flying out to Japan from the US in a few months and I want to bring 2 pieces of luggage, 1 large one for clothes and a small one (not a carry on) for souvenirs when I come back. I plan to pack the small one with my clothes and place it into large one.

Will I have any international issues putting one luggage into another? I assume that as long as I follow the guidelines from the airline I won't have a problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have done this more than once without the slightest notice taken by TSA, Customs, or the airline.

Comment: My sister has travelled back from Kazakhstan to Canada the same way and has not run into issues.

Comment: Airlines that have a one piece hand luggage policy tell their passengers to put the smaller piece into the bigger piece.